Statistical power using mixed models
For computing statistical power of planned contrasts from a (generalized) linear mixed model, I have read that simulation is often used as the design / model is too complex that an analytical formula to compute power is unavailable. However, even if the model is complicated, we might be interested in testing whether an estimated parameter is zero using the t or z distribution. The complexity of the model is just needed to get a better estimate of the parameters and standard errors. So after fitting the model and getting those parameters and standard errors, why not use standard analytical formulas for the t or z power calculation that are readily available in many software packages? Why the need for simulation?

We should not do that because it is working in the wrong order.  Power should be computed before collecting the data.  Before collecting the data we do not have any data to fit the model to in order to get the parameters and standard errors.  So we simulate data based on our best estimates, or minimally interesting differences.  Simulating based on the null hypothesis being true can also tell us if using a z or t approximation is reasonable.
If the data is already analyzed, then there is no need to compute the power.  Computing the "post hoc power" is at best meaningless and can be misleading.  See:
Hoenig, J. M., & Heisey, D. M. (2001). The Abuse of Power: The Pervasive Fallacy of Power Calculations for Data Analysis. The American Statistician, 55(1), 19–24. https://doi.org/10.1198/000313001300339897

I’m aware that post hoc power calculations are flawed. I was thinking of the situation when we are planning to use a mixed model to analyse the data. Can we not just use the analytical formula to compute power (a priori) for any old z test?

@user167591, In theory yes you could, but with all the variances and their covariances, it is probably more complicated than just doing the simulations.  I had a coworker once come to me because he had used 2 different online tools for mixed effects models sample sizes and received 2 very different answers (neither said that it used simulations).  I did some simulations and found an answer similar to one of them.  Was the other one incorrect? it may have been correct for different assumptions than I made, but there was no way to tell.  With simulations you know what your assumptions were.

whilst I understand mixed models estimate variances and covariances, are these not irrelevant when it comes to the power calculation I had in mind? For example the pwr.t.test() function in R does not require the user to specify a variance; it is incorporated implicitly in the Cohen’s D which the user does need to specify.

@user167591, Since the variance is incorporated into Cohen's D, you need an estimate of it to make meaningful effect size estimates.  However, I do use tools like pwr.t.test as a first step approximation for simple models, then use simulation to get more precision, or add in more complexities.
